# Pass value from grid view to new page ASP.NET C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view. 
I want to take the selected row from the grid view and pass on a column value in that row to a new page while storing that value in the session.

So far I know how to store it as a string from a tut, but don't know how to keep the value in int format not convert it to string.

Here is what I have in my C# code...Like I said this does write out the row as a string type I want it to remain a int.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Select")
        {
            Int16 num = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument);
            TextBox2.Text = GridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Text;

        }
    }
```

Putting it into session will be easy. I figured out it is:

```
Session["customerID"] =  GridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Text;
```

So now the true question is how to keep the value in a int format.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not save it in int type directly.Session stores the value in object type. So you have to cast it as int.

```
int customerID = (int) Session["customerID"];
      // or
int customerID = Convert.ToInt32( Session["customerID"].ToString());
     // or
int customerID = int.Parse( Session["customerID"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the value back by doing something like this:

```
var myInt = (int)Session["customerID"]
```

Session variables can store any object, not just strings. You could technically store your whole gridview object in a session variable.